# Symfony2 Custom Form Type w/Data Transformer - Service Injection

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I'm implementing a custom form type with data transformer to fulfill a many-to-many relationship according to http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/data_transformers.html

```
class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('shortname')
            ->add('shortinfo')
            ->add('web')                
            ->add('user', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'     => IntegerType::class,
                'allow_add'      => true,
                'allow_delete'   => true
            ));

        $builder->get('user')->addModelTransformer(new UserToPrimaryKeyTransformer($this->manager));
    }
}
```

The sub-type `UserType` is:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('loginname')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            /* ... */
            ->add('email')
            ->add('id')
        ;
    }
}
```

The transformer class is pretty much copy-pasted from the docs:

```
class UserToPrimaryKeyTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transform entity to pkid
     *
     * @param User
     * @return integer
     */
    public function transform($user)
    {
        if(null === $user) {
            return -1;
        }

        return $user->getId();
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $pkid
     */
    public function reverseTransform($pkid)
    {
        if (!$pkid) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->manager
            ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:User')
            // query for the user with this id
            ->find($pkid)
        ;

        if (null === $user) {
            /* ... */
        }

        return $user;
    }

}
```

So much for the context. The problem, however seems to lie in the service definition, precisely the injection of the Doctrine Entity Manager:

```
acme.form.type.client:
    class: AcmeBundle\Form\ClientType
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
    tags:
       - { name: form.type }
```

Now when I post this form, I get: 
`Type error: Argument 1 passed to AcmeBundle\Form\ClientType::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given`

Any ideas or pointers on what's going on? Does the `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` variable have to be instantiated somewhere?

I'm on Symfony 2.8, btw

Comment: have you a typo in service definition? Because you're saying `AcmeBundle\Form\ClientType` instead of `AcmeBundle\Form\ CrmClientType`

Comment: nope sorry... forgot to simplify that one... should be `AcmeBundle\Form\ClientType` in both cases

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. I forgot that I was manually instantiating the form in order to fulfill an API requirement (it's a REST service I'm developing):

```
// create a form with an empty name in order to avoid needing a JSON ROOT element
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('', new \AcmeBundle\Form\ClientType(), $client);
```

after changing this to

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('', new \AcmeBundle\Form\ClientType($em), $client);
```

it worked.

Thank you all!

Comment: why are you handling dependencies manually? your form type is registered so you can just get it from container

Comment: that's very correct. as stated in the comment above it's necessary to create a form with an empty name in order to remove the JSON root element that would otherwise be necessary. If you had a nicer solution, I'd be delighted!

Comment: what about something like this:
$this->createForm($formType, ['form_alias/name' => $client]);

Comment: Just be aware that passing an actual form type instance to the form factory is depreciated in S2 and gone in S3.  So if you ever plan on upgrading then you will need to do some serious refactoring.  If you are already on S2.8 then just pass the class name of ClientType instead of an instance.  Oddly enough, the service definition will then be used and the entity manager injected for you.

Comment: One more suggestion, define your transformer as a service and inject it into ClientType.  That way, ClientType does not need to fool around with the entity manager.

Comment: thanks @Cerad, passing the class name worked like a charm!

Comment: ... so did injecting the Transformer as service into the form type... thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your form type expecting ObjectManager and you are injecting EntityManager. I suggest to change constructor parameter to EntityManager and it'll be working

Comment: No, that's not true as, first, error says that he's passing null, second, `EntityManager` implements `ObjectManager` (via `EntityManagerInterface`)

Comment: that's correct @DonCallisto, as per the [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html) (it's a little bit hard to find) via `EntityManagerInterface`